# On Submit open the thankyou.html + download the PDF

Tags: php, javascript

I have a simple download form and on submit I want the users to be able to download the PDF and to open in the same time a thank you page.

I tried using window.open and also several PHP methods (headers). While the PHP methods are doing the job of popping up the download pdf screen the page is not redirecting to the thank you page.

Can anyone help either with JS or PHP?

I'm not that savvy with either ones - I will really appreciate if you can share the entire code. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need 3 files:

1. Your file with the form page having:
   `<form action="thanks.php" id="form" method="POST"><!-- your form content and a submit button here--></form>`
2. A **thanks.php** page that will have an:
   `<iframe src="download_pdf.php" style="display:none;" />`
3. AND FINALLY create a **download_pdf.php** page:

```
<?php
 $file = 'filename.pdf';
 if(!file){
     die('Error: file not found');
 }else{
     header("Cache-Control: public");
     header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
     header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
     readfile($file);
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best way will be to open the thankyou form as normal, then on a timeout (use [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)), use [`window.open("url", "_blank")`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) to open the PDF download.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do a PHP redirect with header() before any other content is sent to the browser. Once the page has loaded, you'll need to use JS. This is simple enough with JS:

```
window.location = "http://example.com";
```

I would question loading two windows at once, however. It might be easier to display the Thank You page and provide a link where they can view/download the PDF on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the user should not reuse the thank you page url to repeatedly download pdf that will defeat the purpose of getting the user info in the first place.  So timeout would be necessary in the thank you page where you can show the download.  But check to see if you can mask the url of thankyou page somehow by using a pop up instead.